# How to test react-dropzone with Jest and react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-dropzone

I want to test onDrop method from react-dropzone library in React component. I am using Jest, React Testing Library. I'm creating mock file and I'm trying to drop this files in input, but in console.log files are still equal to an empty array. Do you have any ideas?

**package.json**

```
"typescript": "^3.9.7",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.0.4",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.13",
"jest": "^26.4.2",
"ts-jest": "^26.3.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-dropzone": "^10.1.10",
"@types/react-dropzone": "4.2.0",
```

**ModalImportFile.tsx**

```
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
import { Box, Button, Dialog, DialogContent, DialogTitle, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import AttachFileIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AttachFile";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

interface Props {
    isOpen: boolean;
}

interface Events {
    onClose: () => void;
}

const ModalImportFile: FC<Props & Events> = props => {
    const { isOpen } = props as Props;
    const { onClose } = props as Events;

    const [files, setFiles] = useState<Array<File>>([]);

    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, open } = useDropzone({
        onDrop: (acceptedFiles: []) => {
            setFiles(
                acceptedFiles.map((file: File) =>
                    Object.assign(file, {
                        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
                    }),
                ),
            );
        },
        noClick: true,
        noKeyboard: true,
    });

    const getDragZoneContent = () => {
        if (files && files.length > 0)
            return (
                <Box border={1} borderRadius={5} borderColor={"#cecece"} p={2} mb={2}>
                    <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="space-between">
                        <Box color="text.primary">{files[0].name}</Box>
                        <Box ml={1} color="text.secondary">
                            <Button
                                startIcon={<DeleteIcon color="error" />}
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setFiles([]);
                                }}
                            />
                        </Box>
                    </Grid>
                </Box>
            );
        return (
            <Box border={1} borderRadius={5} borderColor={"#cecece"} p={2} mb={2} style={{ borderStyle: "dashed" }}>
                <Grid container alignItems="center">
                    <Box mr={1} color="text.secondary">
                        <AttachFileIcon />
                    </Box>
                    <Box color="text.secondary">
                        <Box onClick={open} component="span" marginLeft="5px">
                            Download
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Box>
        );
    };

    const closeHandler = () => {
        onClose();
        setFiles([]);
    };

    return (
        <Dialog open={isOpen} onClose={closeHandler}>
            <Box width={520}>
                <DialogTitle>Import</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <div data-testid="container" className="container">
                        <div data-testid="dropzone" {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}>
                            <input data-testid="drop-input" {...getInputProps()} />
                            {getDragZoneContent()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </DialogContent>
            </Box>
        </Dialog>
    );
};

export default ModalImportFile;
```

**ModalImportFile.test.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import ModalImportFile from "../../components/task/elements/ModalImportFile";

const props = {
    isOpen: true,
    onClose: jest.fn(),
};

beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

describe("<ModalImportFile/>", () => {
    it("should drop", async () => {
        render(<ModalImportFile {...props} />);

        const file = new File([JSON.stringify({ ping: true })], "ping.json", { type: "application/json" });
        const data = mockData([file]);

        function dispatchEvt(node: any, type: any, data: any) {
            const event = new Event(type, { bubbles: true });
            Object.assign(event, data);
            fireEvent(node, event);
        }

        function mockData(files: Array<File>) {
            return {
                dataTransfer: {
                    files,
                    items: files.map(file => ({
                        kind: "file",
                        type: file.type,
                        getAsFile: () => file,
                    })),
                    types: ["Files"],
                },
            };
        }
        const inputEl = screen.getByTestId("drop-input");
        dispatchEvt(inputEl, "dragenter", data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems the official test example provided on dropzone's side is so bad and confusing and some parts not working in action. do you find any way to test components contains this component and drop event?

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani I rewrote the test component, please see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about changing `fireEvent(node, event);` to `fireEvent.drop(node, event);`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It didn't help me. Files are still equal to an empty array

Comment: I changed `fireEvent(node, event);` to `fireEvent.drop(node, event);` and 
I added `await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText("ping.json")).toBeInTheDocument());` to the last line and the test passed.

Answer (score 13):

With the rokki`s  answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64643985/9405587), I rewrote the test component for easier understanding.

**ModalImportFile.test.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import ModalImportFile from "../../components/task/elements/ModalImportFile";

const props = {
    isOpen: true,
    onClose: jest.fn(),
};

beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

describe("<ModalImportFile/>", () => {
    it("should drop", async () => {
        render(<ModalImportFile {...props} />);
        window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => "url");
        const inputEl = screen.getByTestId("drop-input");
        const file = new File(["file"], "ping.json", {
            type: "application/json",
        });
        Object.defineProperty(inputEl, "files", {
            value: [file],
        });
        fireEvent.drop(inputEl);
        expect(await screen.findByText("ping.json")).toBeInTheDocument();
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me, not sure why not

Answer (score 5):

Although the accepted answer does trigger the event `onDrop`, that wasn't enough for me to test with `useDropzone()` because the hook's states, like `acceptedFiles`, weren't updated.

I found [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/enbw1?file=/src/tests/App.test.tsx:708-1195) code snippet that uses `userEvent.upload(<input>, <files>)` to upload files to the nested `<input>`. I'm gonna paste the relevant code here in case the link is gone.

***App.test.tsx***

```
test("upload multiple files", () => {
  const files = [
    new File(["hello"], "hello.geojson", { type: "application/json" }),
    new File(["there"], "hello2.geojson", { type: "application/json" })
  ];

  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);
  const input = getByTestId("dropzone") as HTMLInputElement;
  userEvent.upload(input, files);

  expect(input.files).toHaveLength(2);
  expect(input.files[0]).toStrictEqual(files[0]);
  expect(input.files[1]).toStrictEqual(files[1]);
});
```

***App.tsx***

```
export default function App() {
  
  const {
    acceptedFiles,
    isDragActive,
    isDragAccept,
    isDragReject,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps
  } = useDropzone({ accept: ".geojson, .geotiff, .tiff" });

  useEffect(() => console.log(acceptedFiles), [acceptedFiles]);

  return (
    <section>
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <input data-testid="dropzone" {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Notice that the element set as `data-testid="dropzone"` is the `<input>`, and not the `<div>`. That's required so `userEvent.upload` can adequately perform the upload.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked in my case. userEvent being up-to date compated to fireEvent makes this a latest soltion.

Answer (score 0):

References:
https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename

`requireActual`

> Returns the actual module instead of a mock, bypassing all checks on whether the module should receive a mock implementation or not.

```
let dropCallback = null;
let onDragEnterCallback = null;
let onDragLeaveCallback = null;

jest.mock('react-dropzone', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-dropzone'),
  useDropzone: options => {
    dropCallback = options.onDrop;
    onDragEnterCallback = options.onDragEnter;
    onDragLeaveCallback = options.onDragLeave;

    return {
      acceptedFiles: [{
          path: 'sample4.png'
        },
        {
          path: 'sample3.png'
        }
      ],
      fileRejections: [{
        file: {
          path: 'FileSelector.docx'
        },
        errors: [{
          code: 'file-invalid-type',
          message: 'File type must be image/*'
        }]
      }],
      getRootProps: jest.fn(),
      getInputProps: jest.fn(),
      open: jest.fn()
    };
  }
}));


it('Should get on drop Function with parameter', async() => {
  const accepted = [{
      path: 'sample4.png'
    },
    {
      path: 'sample3.png'
    },
    {
      path: 'sample2.png'
    }
  ];
  const rejected = [{
    file: {
      path: 'FileSelector.docx'
    },
    errors: [{
      code: 'file-invalid-type',
      message: 'File type must be image/*'
    }]
  }];

  const event = {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false,
    currentTarget: null,
    defaultPrevented: true,
    eventPhase: 3,
    isDefaultPrevented: () => {},
    isPropagationStopped: () => {},
    isTrusted: true,
    target: {
      files: {
        '0': {
          path: 'FileSelector.docx'
        },
        '1': {
          path: 'sample4.png'
        },
        '2': {
          path: 'sample3.png'
        },
        '3': {
          path: 'sample2.png'
        }
      }
    },
    timeStamp: 1854316.299999997,
    type: 'change'
  };
  dropCallback(accepted, rejected, event);
  onDragEnterCallback();
  onDragLeaveCallback();
  expect(handleFiles).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```